# problem with different sites css to my customised button

Tags: css

I have developed one button with the customised way. I have developed the project like we have give this button to other websites to provide communication to their customers.

When they put our  button in their websites their button css works on this button. It looking very hard. and our custom css is disappeared.

How to restrict the other sites css to my button.

Please suggest on this.

Thanks & Regards,

C.GOvindarajulu.

Answer (score 0):

If thats really the case, then whoever is including your button in their page must also acknowledger your CSS rules. And "How to restrict the other sites css to my button."? There is nothing you can do to force others pages to behave the way you want.